# Query dataframe of sports data by winner/loser name, and get tables of aggregate stats per-player?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a CSV dataset of tennis match results in winner, loser format that has similar structure to this one: https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016

I want to create another table that will show number of wins, losses, days since last match, average serve percentage etc. per player.

A friend suggested trying something like this:

```
games = [
    ["Elliot", 7, "Maya", 10],
    ["Elliot", 10, "Brendan", 8],
    ["Jamie", 7, "Omid", 10],
    ["Elliot", 6, "Jamie", 10],
    ["Brendan", 7, "Jamie", 10],
]

players = {}
K = 32.0
game_number = 1

for game in games:
    p1name, p1score, p2name, p2score = game
    if p1name not in players:
        players[p1name] = {
            'wins': 0,
            'losses': 0,
            'score': 1000.0,
        }
    if p2name not in players:
        players[p2name] = {
            'wins': 0,
            'losses': 0,
            'score': 1000.0,
        }
```

more code...

...

```
print('Rank         Player         Elo       Wins    Losses')
rank = 1
for player, p in sorted(players.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1]['score'], item[0]), reverse=True):
    print('%4s %20s %7.1f %5s %7s' % (rank, player, p['score'], p['wins'], p['losses']))
    rank += 1
```

I tried to tweak this code to my needs by making my df a list of lists:

```
lol = df.values.tolist()
players = {}
for game in lol:
    game_id, tournament_name, tournament_id, tournament_date, round_match, winner, winner_id, loser, loser_id, winner_elo, 
    loser_elo, winner_delta, loser_delta, winner_set_1, loser_set_1, winner_set_2, loser_set_2, winner_set_3, loser_set_3,
    winner_set_4, loser_set_4, winner_set_5, loser_set_5, winner_sets, loser_sets, winner_serve_points_won, 
    loser_serve_points_won, winner_serve_hold, loser_serve_hold, winner_points_won, loser_points_won, winner_true_serve_pct, 
    loser_true_serve_pct = game
```

where all the above are the column names in my original df

but I get this error:
 `NameError: name "game_id" is not defined`

The original code works fine but I don't understand why the =game doesn't work on my case.

Am I missing something? Is there a better approach to this problem? My dataset has around 60k instances and 33 columns

Edit: Got the solution, the variables = game should be just in one line. But you're welcome to comment if there is a better solution to achieve what I described in the comments

Edit: columns info

```
game/tournament/winner/loser_id = unique id's

tournament_name = matches are played in daily tournaments

tournament_date = date of tournament/match

round_match = round of tournament the match takes place

winner/loser= winner/loser name

winner/loser_elo = current elo for the day

winner/loser_delta = delta change after match

winner/loser_set_1,2,3,4,5 = score for winner/loser per game, match ends when a player reaches 3 games, 11 points needed to win a game or 2 point differential (extra points if game is tied at 10-10)

winner/loser_sets= number of sets

winner/loser_points_won = total points per player in the match

winner/loser_true_serve_pct = % of points player wins when he is serving

winner_serve_points_won/loser_serve_points_won is obsolete

winner_serve_hold/loser_serve_hold will be replaced by winner/loser_true_serve_pct
```

Comment: I'm working with a pandas dataframe, all the variables you seen in the last code ( game_id, tournament_name etc = game) are the headers of my columns in the df. I tried to get the most recent date each player played a game to find out their most recent elo. I grouped by 'winner', then sorted by date and got the max date. I did the same for 'loser', but I couldn't find a way to compare the maxdates between the same player and get a value from the 'elo' column (if for most recent date the player was a 'winner' then I need 'winner_elo', if loser I need 'loser_elo')

Comment: So apart from getting the count of wins and losses the rest seem pretty hard to deal with pandas and this list of lists to dictionary seems like a good solution

Comment: Hmm, if you're generating multiple output columns at once, please write out the spec in pseudocode for 'winner', max date (newest?) / 'loser', 'elo' / 'winner_elo' / 'loser_elo'; I can't follow your comment. It helps if you show a simple example of how this stuff is computed, like for say 6-10 records. (Also, this is very dataset-specific, that [Kaggle competition's kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016/kernels) will usually show some good Exploratory Data Analysis, or else post your own for feedback from people who know that dataset).

Comment: Previous asking of same question with less detail [Update value for every row based on either of two previous columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059474/update-value-for-every-row-based-on-either-of-two-previous-columns)

Comment: Sorry for underestimating your question - this is harder than at first glance - we can't just use `df.groupby()`. You need to **query the dataframe for player name occurring in either 'Winner' or Loser' column**. That's the hardest part to get right; the rest is easier.

Comment: Hey I don't see how you derive the columns `winner_serve_points_won, loser_serve_points_won, winner_serve_hold, loser_serve_hold, winner_points_won, loser_points_won, winner_true_serve_pct, loser_true_serve_pct` from [the 53 columns in that dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016), how do you compute them? The granularity of that data only goes down to set-level, not game-level?!

Comment: The original title buried the hard and origianal part of this question - I tried to edit it to reflect, please update it accordingly. It's good for the question body to succinctly state the question, and not be overly reliant on a specific dataset. Also, please summarize and edit any needed parts of your clarification comments above into the question body.

Comment: For the question about computing winner_/loser_elo by date, can you ask a new question, link to your dataset URL (yours is different to Kaggle's), and show a couple of player records with date and URL and how you're trying to calculate it. You'll want to add the options `read_csv(..., parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)` to read those DD/MM/YYYY format dates as dates.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to query the dataframe for player name occurring in either 'Winner' or Loser' column, to get `matches`, a dataframe of all matches involving that player. This is harder than at first glance - we can't just use a simple `df.groupby()`.** Sorry for underestimating your question.

- Solution below uses **`df[['Winner','Loser']].isin([player]).any(axis=1)`**

  - Note that parameterizes the list of columns where the name can occur, it doesn't hardcode them. More elegant idiom than `df['Winner'] == player or df['Loser'] == player`
  - I also looked into `df.query("...")` which takes arbitrary SQL-style query string, but its syntax is annoying
- There are 1387 unique players across both columns: 879 unique players in `df['Winner']` and 1383 in `df['Loser']`. We combine both those into one set `player_names`. You could use lists but it's easier to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?set-types-set-frozenset#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove duplicates: `set(df['Winner'].unique()) | set(df['Loser'].unique())` where '|' is the setwise-'or'/`.union`.
- For efficiency in handling player names, we use a categorical instead of string. Note how the code has to take to have **one unified categorical with merged categories values across both 'Winner','Loser' columns** (see code).
- We use a `defaultdict(dict)` for `players`, this is elegant because now you can just directly define fields `players[player]['WhateverField']` regardless whether the dict `players[player]` is defined, if not it will be automatically created.
- Code here shows examples of the aggregate fields you want to create.

  - note how you can directly used pandas vectorized `mean()`, `sum()`, etc. for simple stuff
  - to create other more arbitrary aggregations, you could use `matches.agg(...)` with a custom/lambda function inside.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016
df = pd.read_csv('../input/Data.csv', encoding='latin1', usecols=range(12+1), na_values='NR',
    parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
# make sure that the 'NR' in WRank/LRank column is recognized as NaN, so they read in as float columns
# Columns 0-12 (basic data), 13-25 (results by set), 26-53 (betting odds: float)

# Create table of number of wins, losses, days since last match, average serve percentage etc. per player.

pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
pd.options.display.precision = 3    

player_names = set(df['Winner'].unique()) | set(df['Loser'].unique())
player_names = sorted(player_names) # 1.0.x BUG: order seems totally unstable(!)
player_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories = player_names) # merge across multiple columns

# WRONG: categories only taken from each individual column, not merged
# df[['WinnerCat1','LoserCat1']] = df[['Winner','Loser']].astype('category')
# RIGHT:
df[['WinnerCat','LoserCat']] = df[['Winner','Loser']].astype(player_dtype)

from collections import defaultdict
players = defaultdict(dict)

for _,player in (player_names):
    # query df where player occurs in either column, can't use `df[['Winner','Loser']].groupby(player)`
    matches = df[ df[['Winner','Loser']].isin([player]).any(axis=1) ]

    print(f'\n[MATCHES FOR {_} {player}]')
    print(matches.iloc[:, 0:13])

    players[player]['Wins']   = matches['Winner'].eq(player).sum()
    players[player]['Losses'] = matches['Loser'].eq(player).sum()
    players[player]['Avg']    = matches['Winner'].eq(player).mean().round(4)
    # You can do any arbitrary calculation involving both players' columns, e.g....
    players[player]['RankDiff'] = (matches['WRank'] - matches['LRank']).mean()

    #if _ >= 2: break # for debugging
```

Comment: Hey smci, thanks for your effort and for editing the title (sometimes I struggle to ask the correct question).

Firstly, I'm beginner to intermediate that's why I'm working on this project to "do and learn" and then be able to show a complete project. One of my goals is to apply some prediction techniques to this dataset (logit regression, markov chains, monte Carlo simulations) just for experimenting. The other is to be able to show individual stats per player as there is no other source for this league. Part of this goal is to be able to have everything on a website I plan to create

Comment: I edited the post and added some explanation on my columns. I scraped this data from a website about ping pong and formatted it in similar structure to the dataset I linked before. The only sources that are doing something similar to what I'm looking for is:

1) https://www.kaggle.com/sadz2201/tennis-exploration-atpboost , but it's written in R and I can't understand what he is doing

2) https://medium.com/@elliotchance/elo-rating-system-implemented-in-single-sql-select-9511bdff6434 , this is in SQL and the outcome is a bit different but the idea is there

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't have much time before the weekend but I'm commenting to know I didn't ignore your answer. I tried your code but don't have much time to experiment with it. Could you explain how this works? `player_names = set(df.Winner.unique()) | set(df.Loser.unique())` and what exactly this means? `#if _ >= 2: break # for debugging`.

I ran the code and did some experiments. If I understand right, the first line after the for loop starts creates a df for every player (where he is either in 'winner' or 'loser' right?

Comment: I tried to do `players[player]['avg_serve_win'] = matches['winner_true_serve_pct'].eq(player).mean()` but it always returns 0 and I doubt it's correct, because if above we created a df for each player where he appears in 'winner' or 'loser' then to get the 'winner_true_serve_pct' average we'd need to get this value only from rows where player is a winner. I'm not sure if I'm being clear enough, hope you understand what' I'm trying to say. I'm not sure if this whole thing is something too hard for me, If you want I can give you or upload a sample dataset to better understand the problem

Comment: Clarification about `#if _ >= 2: break # for debugging` : I do get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` but since '_' is only used for the print statement I just removed it. But was curious on what you mean `break # for debugging`

Comment: idontknowmuch: yeah that's just my standard debugging trick to only see the first few results, to visually debug from the print statements if things are working. `break` just exits the loop after a few iterations. `# for debugging` is just a trailing comment, it gets ignored, it's not Python commands.

Comment: Columns like `winner_true_serve_pct` doesn't exist in the Kaggle 53-column dataset , as I mentioned in my comment above, it only has set-level data granularity, not game- or point-level. Hence `matches['winner_true_serve_pct']` won't work. Are you perhaps using a different version of the dataset, with extra columns? If so, please post the URL in your question. Anyway you get the general idea.

Comment: I've added a description of my columns in my question, I hope you can understand. About true serve percentage, in each match there is a `winner_true_serve_pct` and a `loser_true_serve_pct` which is a percentage of how many points the winner/loser won when serving. So to find a player's average serve percentage, I need to be able to get values from `winner_true_serve_pct` when he is a winner and `loser_true_serve_pct` when is he is a loser and then find the average. To do that is your approach suitable? Also can you explain the purpose of winnerCAT/loserCAT? Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

If you have a csv file, for example, load it in like that

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read.csv('file.csv')
```

Now, select the columns that interest you(i'll use the kaggle database as reference).

Note that i won't wrote everything that you asked because i didn't understand your question completely(there's not date on the kaggle database, and average of what per player?)

```
dataframe = dataframe['Winner', 'Loser']
```

Now, we use the groupby function along with the count function to get the amount of wins and  losses of each player(along with making its appeareance on the "Winner"/"Loser" columns unique.

```
dataframe['Wins'] = dataframe.groupby(labels='Winner', axis=1).count()
dataframe['Losses'] = dataframe.groupby(labels='Loser', axis=1).count()
```

Comment: Hey, as I said my dataset is similar to the kaggle one I linked. You can see my columns in the last piece of code. Actually there is a date column on the kaggle dataset too.

I'm aware to get the count of wins and losses has a solution similar to yours but what I want to do I cannot achieve it with any combinations of groupby,sortby I tried. For instance, as you have realised the same player can appear both in the winner and the loser column,

Comment: [p2 of comment]


I'd like to be able to get the latest instance of each player so I can get the most up to date Elo value from the 'elo' column. Similarly, for each match every player has a percentage serve and percentage hold, I'd like to have the average per player. Or by how many points a player wins a set on average.. and stuff like that. I thought the sample code my friend provided was a nice idea but I don't understand why I get that error

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code without any errors so I dont think its an issue with the = game.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Ten.csv')


lol = df.values.tolist()


players = {}
for game in lol:
    Player,Tournament,Wins,Losses = game

    if Player not in players:
        players[Player] = {
            'Tournament': 'foo',
            'wins': 1,
            'losses': 2,
        }

print(players)
```

However if Player is different such as the following (lowercase "p")

```
player,Tournament,Wins,Losses = game
```

or: (an "s" at the end of [Player])

```
        players[Players] = {
            'Tournament': 'foo',
            'wins': 1,
            'losses': 2,
        }
```

the error  NameError: name 'Player' is not defined  will pop up.  Are you 100% sure that game_id isn't being misspelled somewhere?

Comment: I used my df column names in that "=game" but if I understand it right it doesn't matter what names you use as long as they are matching the list. For instance, any name I put it gives me the same error - it doesn't matter if it's game_id first or not. In the original code I used; p1name, p1score, p2name, p2score are not defined anywhere else and if you put other names it stills works as long as it's 4 variables that match the lists.

Comment: Right on, yeah you can name them whatever you want. But I am suspecting that there is an inconsistency in names somewhere after the =game. For example, I could have done A,B,C,D = game. But then if I tried to call players [a] instead of players [A] I will get the NameError:name 'a' is not defined. Weird that it worked with  p1name, p1score, p2name, p2score and not the new names you are trying